# Gulp + Browsersync: tarea del server no funciona

Tags: nodejs, sass, gulp, pug

Estoy aprendiendo a desarrollar con las tecnologías de node, y me encontré con el siguiente problema:
Estoy usando gulp para gestionar tareas de sass y pug, junto a browsersybc; el punto es que a la hora de ejecutar la tarea de browsersyn esta no hace nada, no me muestra error y dice que se ha ejecutado bien  . He aqui la salida por consola...

```
[22:49:47] Using gulpfile C:\xampp\htdocs\curso-gulp-desde-cero\gulpfile.js
[22:49:47] Starting 'serversync'...
[22:49:47] Starting 'sass'...
[22:49:47] Finished 'sass' after 272 ms
[22:49:47] Finished 'serversync' after 281 ms
```

Me gusstaria saber que hice mal, aqui el gulpfile que estoy usando

```
//modules-importations
const gulp = require('gulp'),
      sass = require('gulp-sass'),
      autoPrefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
      pug = require('gulp-pug');

const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create()


//create-gulp-task
//sass-task
gulp.task('sass', ()=>{
    return gulp.src('./dev/scss/styles.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            outputStyle: 'compact'
        }))
        .pipe(autoPrefixer({
            overrideBrowserslist: ["last 1 version"]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

//pug-task
gulp.task('pug', ()=>{
    return gulp.src('./dev/pug/*.pug')
        .pipe(pug({
            pretty: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'))
})

//server-task
gulp.task('serversync', gulp.series('sass'), ()=> {

    browserSync.init({
        server: "./public"
    });

});
```

He de mencionar que no estoy usando babel aun.
Agradeceré  su ayuda.